# UICollectionView reuse in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I know this question is already ask many times but non of the solution will work.

I have collection view in uitableview cell and i prepare a cell of table view and collection view in story board and my problem is that suppose i scroll cell 1 collection view then cell 4 collection is auto scroll to that position also. How i can handle this situation..

> Please note right now i make a static design of the screen

My code

```
// MARK:
    // MARK: table view delegate method

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if Appconstant.isIpad()
        {
            return 215.0
        }
        return 185.0

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let strCell = "WorkoutCell" //+ "\(indexPath.row)"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(strCell) as? WorkoutCell
//        if cell == nil
//        {
//            cell = work 
//        }
        return cell!
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell2 = cell as! WorkoutCell
        cell2.collecionWorkout.reloadData()
    }
    // MARK:
    // MARK: collectionview delegate and data source
    //1
    func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
     func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //2
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // Adjust cell size for orientation
        if Appconstant.isIpad() {
            return CGSize(width: 160, height: 150)
        }
        return CGSize(width: 140.0, height: 130.0)
    }
    //3
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("WorkoutCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        // Configure the cell
        return cell
    }
```

> uitableview cell code

```
class WorkoutCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collecionWorkout: UICollectionView!
    var flowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        if Appconstant.isIpad()
        {
            self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 160, height: 150)
        }
        else
        {
            self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 140, height: 130)
        }
        self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
        self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0);
        collecionWorkout.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

> Cell 1st which i scroll

[image]

> cell 4th which auto scroll

[image]

Comment: looks like thie 4. cell is reuesed and takes all stuff from cell 1. This is right, you have to react on the reuse. In your cell class you need to override the func, 'prepareForReuse' there u should reset the content, scroll positions or whatever

Comment: @BjörnRo but it also effect to actual scroll cell too. I don't think this is solution

Comment: yes thats true, but this is how it works. if your cell goes outside of the screen, then it gets reused for the new cell. So it will use everything that was in the cell before

Comment: If you want every collectionView stay as it is, than you cant use a TableViewController. Than you should just use containers that implement your CollectionViewController everytime.

Comment: The way to do this only you have to store offset position of each collection view and set each time when table view is in reloading.

Comment: Try using a `stack` of `collectionViews` inside the `scrollView` in case you want to retain the state of `collectionView` indexes.

Comment: in prepareforreuse reset the offset of collection view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two scenarios.

**1 - Reset The UICollectionView offset position :**

To Reset the collectionview position just call `cell.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero` in cellForRowAtIndexPath

**2 - Maintain the previous scroll position  :**

To Maintain the previous scroll position, You'll need to have a list of offsets for each cell stored alongside your data models in the containing view controller. Then you might save the offset for a given cell in `didEndDisplayingCell` and setting it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `.zero` .

Comment: for first scenario i am using prepareForReuse function. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`UITableView` works on the concept of `reusability`. Whenever the `tableView` is scrolled, the `cells` in the `tableView` will definitely be reused.

Now 2 scenarios arise with this,

1. **Get a new cell** - When the `tableViewCell` is reused, the `collectionView` inside it also will be reused and so this is the reason the `contentOffset` of the previous cell is retained.
2. `Scroll to previous cell` - if we've manually scrolled to a particular `cell` in the `collectionView`, we might want to retain its position when we scroll back to it.

To get this kind of functionality in `tableView`, we need to - manually reset the `contentOffset` for `1st case` and need to retain the `contentOffset` in the 2nd one.

Another approach you can follow is using a **`combination of UIScrollview and UIStackView`**.

This is how it goes.

1. In `storyboard`, create a UIScrollView. Add a vertical UIStackView to it.
2. Add 4 `UICollectionViews` in the `stackView`. This number is configurable as per your requirement.
3. Add your `controller` as the `dataSource` and `delegate` of all the `collectionViews`.

i.e.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

Now, since we're using a `stackView`, none of the `collectionViews` will be reused. So, the `contentOffsets` of the all the `collectionViews` will remain intact.

[image]

Comment: It might be difficult to manage this solution if the collection views number is never the same. In this case, you will need to create an array of collections views, and then iterate through it in order to populate the stack view. It seems quite overriding the purpose of a table view, isn't it?

Comment: Ofcourse that is the only drawback. Everything must be handled manually in this approach.